# Java FileLock on a file and delete it on exit

Tags: java, linux, io, locking, nio

I have two JVM processes running, say **Process1** and **Process2**. Each process is running the following:

```
File lockFile = new File("lock");
if (!lockFile.exists()) {
    lockFile.createNewFile();
}

RandomAccessFile lockRAF = new RandomAccessFile(lockFile, "rw");

FileChannel channel = lockRAF.getChannel();
FileLock fileLock;
try {
    fileLock = channel.tryLock();
} catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
    ...
} ...

// do something exclusive

fileLock.release();
lockRAF.close();

lockFile.delete();
```

(Not showing exception handling since it is not the main point of the question).

The problem comes from deleting the file at the end where:

- *Process1* acquires a FileLock, does some work then releases it
- *Process2* acquires a lock
- *Process1* deletes the file
- *Process1* then tries to call the same code snippet again. This works because it creates a new file from which a lock is acquired.
- **The result is that both processes have acquired a lock which was supposed to be exclusive.**

**Note:** this happens on Linux (Windows does not allow deleting the file when locked).

How can I solve this in a way that allows the lock file to be deleted at the end? File.deleteOnExist does not solve the issue.

Comment: this answer corresponds to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/5715507/7237884

Comment: for different jvm the lock method that you use is not safe

Comment: To use a file as a semaphore, I would not use a FileLock at all.  Instead, just use [Files.createFile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)).  From the documentation: “Creates a new and empty file, failing if the file already exists. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the new file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the directory.”